# Printing a certain number of lines in a list

Tags: python

One of my homework questions requires me to write a function that has two parameters. One is a list of strings (of earthquake information) and the second is a number. If the number is -1, then it has to print each earthquake string in the list, one per line. If the number is 1 or more, then it has to print only that many earthquake strings, starting with the first one in the list. If the number is larger than the number of earthquake strings then it has to print all the earthquake strings.  So far I have the following:

```
    def printQuakes(alist, num):
        if num == -1:
            for line in alist:
                return alist
        elif num >= 1:
            for line in alist:
                return alist[num]
```

It prints the entire list of information when I print the function with -1, but not one per line.  And then the second part of the code only prints the line that corresponds with the number in the parameter.  I know that it's because I have alist[num], but I don't know how to make it return all the lines before that, as the question asks me to do.  How can I change the code to print one per line when the parameter is -1, and how can I print the same number of lines as the parameter calls for when the parameter is 1 or higher.  Thank you so much, everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `alist[:num]` to select the `num` first elements of the list

```
def printQuakes(alist, num):
    if num == -1:
        for line in alist:
            print line
    elif num >= 1:
        for line in alist[:num] :
            print line
```

Comment: glad to help @ari.montario :)